# Split a rod of unit length into two at a random position to get two pieces length x and y. Then split both pieces into two again at random positions.

Tags: probability

Suppose y>x.

What is the probability that the smaller segment of the piece initially split into length y is bigger than the bigger segment initially split into length x?

I ran a simulation and got roughly 47.7% chance but cannot show this analytically.

Comment: Note that $x$ is uniformly distributed in $[0, 1/2]$.  Call the two final segments $w$ (from $x$) and $z$ (from $y$).  Observe that, conditioned on $x$, $w$ is uniformly distributed in $[x/2, x]$, and $z$ is uniformly distributed in $[0, (1-x)/2]$.  Does that help?

Comment: You will do nothing if you don't give names ! Let $X_1\ge X_2$ and $Y_1 \ge Y_2$ with $X_1+X_2=X$ and $Y_1+Y_2=Y$ the Random Variables. You want $P(Y_2 > X_1)$.

Comment: @BrianTung can you explain a bit more please

Answer (score 2):

The length $x$ of the shorter piece of the original rod is unifomly distributed in $\bigl[0,{1\over2}\bigr]$. The length $u$ of the larger part of this piece is then uniformly distributed in $\bigl[{x\over2},x\bigr]$, and the length $v$ of the smaller part of the larger piece is uniformly distributed in the interval $\bigl[0,{1-x\over2}\bigr]$. It folows that the point $(u,v)$ is uniformly distributed in the rectangle $R_x:=\bigl[{x\over2},x\bigr]\times\bigl[0,{1-x\over2}\bigr]$ of area ${x(1-x)\over4}$.

We now have to consider the part  $T_x\subset R_x$ where $v\geq u$. If $0\leq x\leq{1\over3}$ the set $T_x$ is a trapezoid of area
$${\rm area}(T_x)={x\over2}\left({1-x\over2}-{3x\over4}\right)={x(2-5x)\over8}\qquad\bigl(0\leq x\leq{1\over3}\bigr)\ .$$
If ${1\over3}\leq x\leq{1\over2}$ then $T_x$ is a triangle of area 
$${\rm area}(T_x)={1\over2}\left({1-x\over2}-{x\over2}\right)^2={(1-2x)^2\over8}\qquad\bigl({1\over3}\leq x\leq{1\over2}\bigr)\ .$$
The probability we are after is then given by
$$p=\int_0^{1/2}{{\rm area}(T_x)\over{\rm area}(R_x)}\>2dx=\int_0^{1/3}{2-5x\over1-x}\>dx+\int_{1/3}^{1/2}{(1-2x)^2\over x(1-x)}\>dx=1-\log{27\over16}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C$ be independent random variable, uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. We have $y=\max(A,1-A), x=\min(A,1-A)$ and we want to compute the probability that

$$\min(B,1-B)\cdot \max(A,1-A) \geq \max(C,1-C)\cdot \min(A,1-A).$$
The distribution of $M=\max(A,1-A)$ is constant and supported on $\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$. Similarly,the distribution of $\min(A,1-A)$ is constant and supported on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. For a given value of $M$, the probability that $M\min(B,1-B)\geq (1-M)\max(C,1-C)$ equals
$$ \frac{(2M-1)^2}{2M(1-M)} $$
if $M\leq\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{5}{2}-\frac{3}{2M}$ if $\frac{2}{3}\leq M\leq 1$. The wanted probability is so
$$ \color{red}{1-3\log 3+4\log 2}\approx 47.675\%.$$

Comment: How did you arrive at $\frac{(2M-1)^2}{2M(1-M)}$?

Comment: @Remy: wa have a random variable $U$ uniformly distributed over $[0,M/2]$ and a random variable $V$ uniformly distributed over $[(1-M)/2,(1-M)]$. By symmetry, the probability that $U\geq V$ is half the probability that both $U$ and $V$ take values in $[(1-M)/2,M/2]$.

Comment: If $M\geq 2/3$ the interval $[(1-M)/2,(1-M)]$ is contained in the interval $[0,M/2]$ and we have to adjust such argument accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We split the unit-length rod without bias and designate the smaller piece's length as $x$ and the larger piece's length as $y$.   We repeat the process on that larger piece and designate its smaller length as $z$.

We assert that since the break is made without bias, and the smaller piece will be less than half the length of the original rod, while the larger piece will be greater than half, therefore $x\sim\mathcal U(0;1/2)$ and $y\sim\mathcal U(1/2;1)$.   Further $x=1-y$.

Likewise and $z\mid y\sim\mathcal U(0;y/2)$.   (Note: if $y<2/3$, then $x>1/3$ while $z<1/3$, so $x>z$ most certainly.)

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(z>x) ~&= \mathsf P(z>1-y) \\ &= \int_{1/2}^1 \int_{1-y}^{\max\{y/2,1-y\}} 4y^{-1}\mathrm d z\mathrm d y \\ &= 4\int_{2/3}^1 y^{-1}\int_{1-y}^{y/2} \mathrm d z\mathrm d y &~\because~& y/2>1-y \implies y>2/3\\&= 2-4\ln (3/2) \end{align}$$